# Eclipse warns "variable is not used" on an abstract class?

Tags: java, eclipse

In the following contrived example, `data` is given a warning due to it being unused. Can someone explained why this is something to warn about?

```
public abstract class Worker {

    private Object data;

    public Worker(Object data) {
        this.data = data;
    }

    public abstract Result run();

}
```

The point of course, is that the data object is used, just not in this abstract class. What should I be doing to make this error go away, ie is it an eclipse setting, or am I just doing something wrong.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> The point of course, is that the data object is used, just not in this abstract class.

How? It's private. The subclasses won't be able to see it, unless they're using reflection.

You *could* make it `protected` so that subclasses can see it - or better (IMO), provide a protected `getData()` method.

Comment: Just wondering why you suggest a protected `getData()` method would be better?

Comment: @Jacob: I view fields as an implementation detail, which shouldn't be exposed non-privately other than in truly exceptional cases.

Answer (score 3):

The variable is private to the class, so can't actually be accessed by any subtypes. Since you only ever assign it in your constructor, Eclipse is warning you it isn't used.

If the variable is used by subtypes, start expanding its visibility or add a getter/setter.  If the type isn't used, it should not be passed in in the constructor.

Answer (score 1):

Found the answer! Because the variables are declared `private` they cant be used by the descendants of this class. They need to be declared `protected`